# Extending the prime zeta function to negative values

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, convergence-divergence, analyticity, zeta-functions

Consider the prime zeta function
\begin{align}
    P(s)
    &= \sum_{p \text{ prime}} \frac{1}{p^s} \\
    &= \sum_{n > 0} \frac{\mu(n)}{n} \log \zeta(n s)
\end{align}

It has a singularity at the reciprocal of every squarefree positive integer $n$, since $\mu(n) \neq 0$ and $ns = 1$, where $\zeta$ has a pole. Noting that $\lim_{s \rightarrow 1} \zeta(s)(s-1) = 1$, let

\begin{align}
    f(s)
    &= P(s) + \sum_{n > 0} \frac{\mu(n)}{n} \log (ns - 1) \\
    &= \sum_{n > 0} \frac{\mu(n)}{n} \log [\zeta(n s) (n s - 1)] \\
    &= \sum_{\substack{n > 0 \\ n \neq 1/s}} \frac{\mu(n)}{n} \log [\zeta(n s) (n s - 1)] \\
\end{align}

Its graph looks like

```
f[s_, max_] := Sum[MoebiusMu[n]/n Log[
    If[n s == 1, 1, Zeta[n s] (n s - 1)]
    ], {n, 1, max}]
Plot[{
  f[s, 1000],
  f[s, 5000]
  }, {s, 0, 2}]
```

[image]

In particular, it seems smooth for all $s > 0$. Can the result be smoothly extended to $s < 0$? If so, is there a limit or convergent series describing this extension? The concepts of [Taylor series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series), [Mittag-Leffler star](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mittag-Leffler_star), and [monodromy theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monodromy_theorem) might be relevant.

**Edit:** Let $g(s) = \log \zeta(s)(s-1)$. Then
\begin{align}
f(s)
&= \sum_{n>0} \frac{\mu(n)}{n} g(ns) \\
f^{(1)}(s)
&= \sum_{n>0} \frac{\mu(n)}{n} \frac{\partial}{\partial s} g(ns) \\
&= \sum_{n>0} \frac{\mu(n)}{n} \frac{\partial ns}{\partial s} \frac{\partial}{\partial ns} g(ns) \\
&= \sum_{n>0} \mu(n) g^{(1)}(ns) \\
f^{(2)}(s)
&= \sum_{n>0} \mu(n) \frac{\partial}{\partial s} g^{(1)}(ns) \\
&= \sum_{n>0} \mu(n) n g^{(2)}(ns) \\
f^{(k)}(s)
&= \sum_{n>0} \mu(n) n^{k-1} g^{(k)}(ns) \\
\end{align}

\begin{align}
f^{(k)}(0)
&= \sum_{n>0} \mu(n) n^{k-1} g^{(k)}(0) \\
&= g^{(k)}(0) \sum_{n>0} \frac{\mu(n)}{n^{1-k}} \\
&= \frac{g^{(k)}(0)}{\zeta(1-k)} \\
&= \frac{(-1)^{k+1} k}{B_k} g^{(k)}(0) \\
f^{(0)}(0)
&= 0 \\
f^{(1)}(0)
&= 2 - 2 \log 2\pi \\
&\approx -1.67575 \\
f^{(2)}(0)
&= 6 + 6 \gamma_0^2 - \frac{\pi^2}{2} + 12 \gamma_1 \\
&\approx 2.19048
\end{align}

However, $B_k = 0$ if $k$ is odd and $k \geq 3$. Does this mean $f^{(k)}(0)$ is undefined for those values? We could potentially regularize $\zeta(1-k)^{-1}$ at those $k$ by taking the Cauchy principal values:

\begin{align}
\zeta(1-k)^{-1}
&\overset{\star}{=} \lim_{s \rightarrow 0} \frac{\zeta(1-k+s)^{-1} + \zeta(1-k-s)^{-1}}{2} \\
&= -\frac{\zeta''(1-k)}{2 \zeta'(1-k)^2}
\end{align}

Comment: @reuns I know $P(s)$ has a natural boundary at $\mathfrak{R}(s) = 0$. What I'm wondering is whether $f$ can be extended in some natural way to negative real values, since it no longer has singularities on the positive real line.

Comment: You need the PNT (that $\sum_n \mu(n)/n$ and $\sum_n \mu(n) \log (n) / n$ both converge) to show your series for $f(s)$ converges, and both $P(s),f(s)$ have a natural boundary on $\Re(s) = 0$ so you can't continue them analytically, why would you want to continue smoothly the restriction of $f$ to $ s > 0$ ? Did you try showing $\lim_{s \to 0^+} f^{(k)}(s)$ converges ? If it does there is a smooth extension based on things like $\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{f^{(k)}(0)}{k!} x^k \phi(e^k x)$ with $\phi \in C^\infty_c$ constant $=1$ on $[-1,1]$

Comment: @reuns Great question. My interest stems from regularizing the divergent series consisting of the sum of all primes, i.e. what the most natural value of $P(-1)$ would be if we could somehow "skip" or "break" or "sneak through" the natural boundary. My thought process is to subtract the logarithmic singularities from $P$, smoothly extend the result to negative values, and then re-add the logarithmic singularities on the positive side.

Comment: @reuns Not sure what you mean. Can you explain?

Comment: Why do you care of $P(s)$ when we have $\log \zeta(s)$ and $\zeta′(s)/\zeta(s)$ ? If $P(s)$ is badly behaved it is not for nothing : maybe the primes aren't truly the building blocks of the integers.. The building block is the sequence $\Lambda(n)$ satisfying $\sum_{d | n} \Lambda(d) = \log n$, the sequence of the primes is just a modified version of it.

Comment: @reuns How do you get $\sum_{p \text{ prime}} p$ from that?